# Instagram API returns images with white border

Tags: javascript, html, css, instagram, instagram-api

Basically I'm working on a website that shows a grid of images from my instagram account via an isotope.js grid and instafeed.js. The images are included as a `background-image` in the CSS. Unfortunately, the images are showing white borders and no matter what I try I don't get the portrait/landscape version.

- The Migrations checkbox is checked in the developer settings
- Accesstoken is right
- resolution is set on 'standard_resolution'
- UserId is right

I've searched on Stackoverflow and Googled a lot, but can't find an answer.

These are my instafeed.js settings

```
// Include Instafeed
function instagram() {
    var feed = new Instafeed({

        // options
        after: isotope,
        get: 'user',
        userId: '230326****',
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        limit: '100',
        // clientId: 'b064a25bd64b4fa4b436fb**********', // client
        accessToken: '2303264036.1677ed0.100a64b6b78c40168e8561**********',
        // template: '<div class="grid-item"><a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a></div>',
        template: '<a href="{{link}}"><div class="grid-item" style="background-image: url({{image}});"><p class="content">View on Instagram</p></div></a>',
        filter: function(image) {
            return image.tags.indexOf('saintpablotour') >= 0;
        }
    });

    feed.run();
}
```

This is the CSS attached

```
.grid-item { 
    width: 250px;  
    height: 250px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Hope anyone can help me with this, since it doesn't really look nice on the page.

Comment: Can you provide the link where we can troubleshoot?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is too obvious and was already done, but is it possible that the white border is a part of the image as it was uploaded?

Comment: @Valius79: The link with the troubles is www.teamkanyedaily.com/tour/ And if you check the above link and click on an image, it shows as a portrait/landscape image on instagram.

Comment: I am confused. This is the screenshot of the page you referenced. http://screencast.com/t/Ef42rzZQtU

Comment: @Valius79 Mmm that's weird. Hope it's fixed now. Here's a screenshot for reference. http://imgur.com/a/pI0Qa Hope this helps.